# How to get distinct row from multiple tables in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables let's say `tableA` and `tableB`:

`TableA`:

```
AID  Another_A_ID 
1        A               
2        A
3        A
4        B
5        B
6        C
```

`TableB`:

```
AID    Name
1       a_a_name
1       a_b_name
1       a_c_name
1       a_d_name
2       a_a_name
2       a_b_name
2       a_c_name
2       a_d_name
3       a_a_name
3       a_a_name
3       a_a_name
3       a_a_name
4       b_a_name
4       b_b_name
5       b_a_name
5       b_b_name
```

How can I get `tableB.name` for each `Another_A_Id` in `tableA`?

Here is what I tried:

```
Select distinct tA.Another_A_ID, tB.name 
from tableA tA
Inner Join tB on tA.AID = tB.AID
```

which yields multiple duplicate rows for `Another_A_ID`

What I am looking here is

```
Another_A_ID    Name
A                a_a_name
A                a_b_name
A                a_c_name
A                a_d_name
B                b_a_name
B                b_b_name
```

Comment: `select distinct` applies to the entire ROW, not just individual fields. e.g. `select distinct foo, distinct bar, baz` will not work.

Comment: Your SQL looks like it should generate the desired result. What are you actually seeing?

Comment: Does "what I am looking here is" mean this is what you're getting (and it's wrong), or this is what you are looking for but not what you are getting? In either case, can you please add more specifics in the question, or be more clear about what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this wouldn't yield the answer you're expecting:

```
SELECT a.Another_A_ID, b.Name
  FROM dbo.tableA AS a
  INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS b
  ON a.AID = b.AID
  GROUP BY a.Another_A_ID, b.Name;
```

In fact, [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ced6/2) proves that your query works (as does mine). If you have left any details out of the question, please add them.